# How to disable M\mouse wheel click paste in VIM?

Tags: mouse, vim, paste, mouse-wheel

Using Ubuntu 20.04, when using vim, clicking mouse wheel works same as pushing 'p' in command mode.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install -y xbindkeys xsel xdotool &&
echo '"echo -n | xsel -n -i; pkill xbindkeys; xdotool click 2; xbindkeys"' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc &&
echo 'b:2 + Release' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc &&
xbindkeys -p &&
echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nName=xbindkeys\nExec=xbindkeys\nComment=Disable middle click paste" >> ~/.config/autostart/xbindkeys.desktop
```

and disabled push mouse wheel to paste in gnome-tweaks

Second changed nothing, and first disabled mouse wheel click paste in other program.
But only vim still pastes something and I hope to disable it

Answer (score 0):

it is a vim setting.
add `set mouse=""` in your `.vimrc` file.
read more about it via `:help mouse`.